# Android Studio - Passing variable with intent add extra, ends up with null

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

after fixing the null pointer exception of a previous question, (Not sure if posting a different question for the same code is okay, do let me know if it is not) I've come across a new problem. When I try passing the date variable from this first activity to another, it is always empty. I've also tried just setting a public getter or the variable and it is also empty. However, using a toast to check within the class shows that the variable does indeed contain the date. I am trying to pass the date class to be added into a database by the other classes in the application package. Any help would be much appreciated.

CalendarActivity.java

```
package com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3.calendar;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3.R;

public class CalendarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_TEXT = "com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3";
    private  static final String TAG = "CalendarActivity";
    private CalendarView mCalendarView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calendar_layout);
        mCalendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        mCalendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView CalendarView, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                String date = year + "/" + month + "/"+ dayOfMonth ;
                Log.d(TAG, "onSelectedDayChange: yyyy/mm/dd:" + date);
                Intent intent = new Intent(CalendarActivity.this,CalendarEvent.class);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,date);
                startActivity(intent);

                Toast.makeText(CalendarActivity.this,date,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

The class I am trying to receive it from : CalendarEvent.java

```
package com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3.calendar;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3.calendar.database.Calendar;
import com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3.calendar.database.CalendarAdapter;
import com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3.calendar.database.Calendar_DbHelper;
import com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3.utils.MyDividerItemDecoration;
import com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3.utils.RecyclerTouchListener;

import com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3.R;


public class CalendarEvent extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CalendarAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<Calendar> notesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private TextView noNotesView;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    public String date;


    private Calendar_DbHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        intent = getIntent();
        date = intent.getStringExtra(CalendarActivity.EXTRA_TEXT);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);




        coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        noNotesView = findViewById(R.id.empty_notes_view);

        db = new Calendar_DbHelper(this);

        notesList.addAll(db.getAllNotes());

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showNoteDialog(false, null, -1);
            }
        });

        mAdapter = new CalendarAdapter(this, notesList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new MyDividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, 16));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        toggleEmptyNotes();



        /**
         * On long press on RecyclerView item, open alert dialog
         * with options to choose
         * Edit and Delete
         * */
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this,
                recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, final int position) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                showActionsDialog(position);
            }
        }));
    }



    /**
     * Inserting new note in db
     * and refreshing the list
     */
    private void createNote(String note) {

        // inserting note in db and getting
        // newly inserted note id
        long id = db.insertNote(note);

        // get the newly inserted note from db
        Calendar n = db.getNote(id);

        if (n != null) {
            // adding new note to array list at 0 position
            notesList.add(0, n);

            // refreshing the list
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            toggleEmptyNotes();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updating note in db and updating
     * item in the list by its position
     */
    private void updateNote(String note, int position) {
        Calendar n = notesList.get(position);
        // updating note text
        n.setNote(note);

        // updating note in db
        db.updateNote(n);

        // refreshing the list
        notesList.set(position, n);
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);

        toggleEmptyNotes();
    }

    /**
     * Deleting note from SQLite and removing the
     * item from the list by its position
     */
    private void deleteNote(int position) {
        // deleting the note from db
        db.deleteNote(notesList.get(position));

        // removing the note from the list
        notesList.remove(position);
        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

        toggleEmptyNotes();
    }

    /**
     * Opens dialog with Edit - Delete options
     * Edit - 0
     * Delete - 0
     */
    private void showActionsDialog(final int position) {
        CharSequence colors[] = new CharSequence[]{"Edit", "Delete"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Choose option");
        builder.setItems(colors, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (which == 0) {
                    showNoteDialog(true, notesList.get(position), position);
                } else {
                    deleteNote(position);
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }


    /**
     * Shows alert dialog with EditText options to enter / edit
     * a note.
     * when shouldUpdate=true, it automatically displays old note and changes the
     * button text to UPDATE
     */
    private void showNoteDialog(final boolean shouldUpdate, final Calendar note, final int position) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflaterAndroid = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
        View view = layoutInflaterAndroid.inflate(R.layout.note_dialog, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilderUserInput = new AlertDialog.Builder(CalendarEvent.this);
        alertDialogBuilderUserInput.setView(view);

        final EditText inputNote = view.findViewById(R.id.note);
        TextView dialogTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title);
        dialogTitle.setText(!shouldUpdate ? getString(R.string.lbl_new_note_title) : getString(R.string.lbl_edit_note_title));

        if (shouldUpdate && note != null) {
            inputNote.setText(note.getNote());
        }
        alertDialogBuilderUserInput
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(shouldUpdate ? "update" : "save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogBox, int id) {

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogBox, int id) {
                                dialogBox.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilderUserInput.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Show toast message when no text is entered
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(inputNote.getText().toString())) {
                    Toast.makeText(CalendarEvent.this, "Enter note!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                } else {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }

                // check if user updating note
                if (shouldUpdate && note != null) {
                    // update note by it's id
                    updateNote(inputNote.getText().toString(), position);
                } else {
                    // create new note
                    createNote(inputNote.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Toggling list and empty notes view
     */
    private void toggleEmptyNotes() {
        // you can check notesList.size() > 0

        if (db.getNotesCount() > 0) {
            noNotesView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            noNotesView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public String getDate(){

        return date;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using wrong key while passing data between activity.

Replace below line,

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,date);
```

With this one,

```
intent.putExtra(CalendarActivity.EXTRA_TEXT,date);
```

Comment: Even after changing the putExtra in my CalendarActivity class as you instructed, the variable still comes out as empty in the next class. Edit: Would it help to add the whole source code to github for reference?

Answer (score 1):

You use the key of Intent.EXTRA_TEXT.

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,date)
```

But you use the other key to receive. It's not the same key.

```
intent.getStringExtra(CalendarActivity.EXTRA_TEXT);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per I know (Not pretty sure)

```
Intent.EXTRA_TEXT
```

is used for implicit intents.

For explicit (i.e.Activity to Activity)

Do as below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CalendarActivity.this,CalendarEvent.class);
intent.putExtra("DATE",date);
startActivity(intent);
```

To receive

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes);
    intent = getIntent();
    String date = intent.getStringExtra("DATE");
}
```

> Where "DATE" is String KEY.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time. After trying to changes you made, the value passed still results in an empty variable.

Comment: @TanZhiJian Just a suggetion.Write intent code down below setContentView in CalendarEvent.class. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Moved it down and sadly it still comes up as empty.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that `CalendarActivity.EXTRA_TEXT` is probably empty because you have not imported that class in to `CalendarEvent.java`

`import com.example.zaphk.studenthelperapplication3.calendar.CalendarActivity;` in `CalendarEvent.java`

and as other people have said the put and get on the Intent need to be the the same String value.

Comment: I would create a local String variable to check that the String you are getting from `CalendarActivity.EXTRA_TEXT` is the correct text, using the debugger to check the local String contents matches the text you used in the `Intent.putExtra`

Comment: I'll give it a try in a bit. thank u for taking the time to help